# Is it possible to join SOAP response using common key in azure APIM

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

Hi is there any way to to join soap response based on any common property in azure apim
e.g.
suppose I have

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body>
        <GetOpenOrdersResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
            <GetOpenOrdersResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/FazioAPISoap" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                <a:OrderSummary>
                    <a:order_header_data>
                        <a:Bar>false</a:Bar>
                        <a:Foo>Things</a:Foo>
                    </a:order_header_data>
                    <a:order_id>10001</a:order_id>
                </a:OrderSummary>
                
            </GetOpenOrdersResult>
        </GetOpenOrdersResponse>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

and i have another response  with other details with same orderid

I have called these apis using send-request policy of apim.
I have tried using context.Variable bbut it is not working out.
Can I merge these response using return-response policy or any other way?

Answer (score 0):

You can apply `Liquid templates` within Azure API Management policies.

```
<outbound>
   <base />

   <!--Create JSON Response via liquid template-->
   <set-body template="liquid">
   {
       "orderId" : "{{body.GetOrderDetailsResponse.OrderId}}",
       "orderDate" : "{{body.GetOrderDetailsResponse.OrderDate | Date: "dd/MM/yyyy"}}",
       "orderLines" : [
           {% JSONArrayFor orderline in body.GetOrderDetailsResponse.OrderLines %}
           {
               "product" : "{{orderline.Product}}",
               "amount" : "{{orderline.Amount}}"
           }
           {% endJSONArrayFor %}
       ]
   }
   </set-body>

   <!--Set correct content type-->
   <set-header name="Content-Type" exists-action="override">
      <value>application/json</value>
   </set-header>
</outbound>
```

The [context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-policy-expressions#ContextVariables) variable is also accessible from within Liquid templates. Inside the Liquid template, you need to apply the following notation: `{{context.Request.Url.Query[“orderId”]}}`.

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://www.codit.eu/blog/using-liquid-templates-in-azure-api-management/?country_sel=be).

Comment: I have 2 responses two merge into 1 based on orderid and i need to use only soap response and not json